# Getting error from entity.eval.inc - null given in array_values() - upon login after upgrading to 7.100 and php to 8.1.2

Tags: log-messages

We recently spun up a new server with newer php.  Tested the new server, converted dns records to now point to the new server, etc.  I was about to take it out of maintenance and noticed drupal had an update.  We were running 7.99.  I figured not much risk, never had a problem updating drupal.  Still, upgraded in test and it seemed fine, upgraded prod and took it out of maintenance.  Now if you log out and log back in you get "The website encountered an error" page.  Reloading the page will get you to the after login screen.

The log showed this error message:
TypeError: array_values(): Argument #1 ($array) must be of type array, null given in array_values() (line 60 of /usr/share/nginx/oursite/sites/all/modules/rules/modules/entity.eval.inc)

I did the same upgrade to 7.100 on the old server and it doesn't have the problem.  It's running php 7.2.24.  Of course, with spinning up a new server there are lots of other things that are updated.

I hack the file and fixed it with this:

`return array('entity_fetched' => is_array($return)? array_values($return): array());`

original code

`return array('entity_fetched' => array_values($return);`

I find it hard to believe there is bug in the code.  I'm guessing we're missing some entity.

Any thoughts on how to fix this properly?

Comment: If the question is actually "how do I debug why `$return` is null", you should actually ask that, and you should provide at minimum a stack trace. There is nothing for anyone to go on here toward knowing why `$return` is null.

Comment: I would have provided a stack trace if there was one.  Nothing I've tried including the Devel module seems to give the trace.  From what I can tell on D7 when you get the "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." message, there often (maybe always) isn't a trace, just the error message.  As I look at this further, I see that the issue is coming out of the rules module.  After many hours debugging, lots of trial and mostly errors, I find a login rule that I guess didn't survive (doesn't work anymore) after the upgrade to php

Answer (score -1):

To properly fix this you should file a bug report, with detailed steps to reproduce. Drupal project pages have in the right-hand column a place to report issues, such a bugs.